# Update a document and get all its fields in 1 query

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a document's id and I would like to retrieve all of its fields while updating some of them **in one query**, optionally as an atomic operation.

I tried the following:

```
myTable.get(id).update(someFields, {returnChanges: true})
```

... but it only gives me the document if it was modified. I want to retrieve the document event when the update did not change any field.

As a tmp workaround, I am currently using two sequential queries: an update, then a get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
myTable
  .get(id)
  .update(someFields, {returnChanges: 'always'})
  ('changes')(0)('new_val')
```

`{returnChanges: 'always'}` tells the db to always return a couple `new_val` / `old_val` even when they are the same.

**Important note**: Using `{returnChanges: 'always'}` will have the side effect of not throwing an exception if the document is not found. Instead, it will return `null` for both `new_val` and `old_val`. Don't rely on an exception in this case.